# Is there a way do MySQL FullText search in Sequelize 4?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to generate a query like the following, using Sequelize 4:

```
SELECT * FROM authors WHERE MATCH (name, altName) AGAINST ('shakespeare');
```

I used to be able to do this:

```
Author.find({
           where: ['MATCH (name, altName) AGAINST (?)',
                  ['shakespeare']]
           })
          .then((result) => {
              console.log(result);
          });
```

but now, after upgrading to Sequelize 4, I get this error:

```
Error: Support for literal replacements in the `where` object has been removed.
```

Answer (score 6):

In Sequelize 4.0+ you can do at this way:

```
Author.find({
    where: Sequelize.literal(`MATCH (name, altName) AGAINST('shakespeare' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)`),
  }).then(…);
```

If you need score a list of records ordered by relevance,  use the example below:

```
Author.findAll({
    attributes: { include:[[Sequelize.literal(`MATCH (name, altName) AGAINST('shakespeare' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)`), 'score']] },
    where: Sequelize.literal(`MATCH (name, altName) AGAINST('shakespeare' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)`),
    order:[[Sequelize.literal('score'), 'DESC']],
  });
```

I hope this help.